# Getting started with PHP / MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

i have been using PHP for quite a sometime now, having understood the concept of OOPS, PDO, etc. i have been slowly moving forward to more advanced PHP. my strategy is always to learn more and more advance programming in every project. for my current project i would like to implement MVC, as i have been implementing my own directory or application structure before, this time i want to use MVC for my application. i did went through a MVC boilerplate tutorial on [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php/). however that was just the basic i am searching for more and more resources for me to help get started with MVC for my projects. i am sure you guys might have passed from the same path i would like to know the links and suggestion about some of the great MVC tutorial for PHP available in the internet.

**EDIT :**

I have used frameworks like cakephp before i would request not to suggest using of any framework.

thank you

Comment: if you need framework , try laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you look at the **MVC Design Pattern** so that you understand it before you start using it.

Ideally, **you should already have made some projects where you suffered a little bit because you wanted to change stuff when your project was at least halfway done.**(This is one of the main motivators behind a lot of so-called *advanced* programming techniques. Ease of modification, flexibility and so on).

This is where stuff like what you mentioned (OO,MVC, and I would add TDD, Design Patterns) all come in).

What I do for myself and suggest others do is the following. Look into whatever you want, be it TDD, MVC or any other *advanced* technique. But wait until you need them.

In my personal opinion, one can much better appreciate the value of OO and MVC when one has gone through a **naïve project** and suffered from lack of functionality these techniques provide...

The golden rule is.. **only start using a new technique when you've understood it and seen what benefits it can bring.**

I say that because what I see in real life is that many people use stuff like OO, MVC and even Design Patterns without understanding the *why's* behind. I don't think that helps at all.

Good luck.

Comment: abuse of patterns is how you end up with the abominations that are widely known as "php frameworks" ..

Comment: Everyone should write their own PHP framework.. but you should never release it. ;)

Comment: Because the considerations - architecture, security, routing, abstractions, etc - are incredibly valuable to learn both in concept and in the tradeoffs that come along with each of the different options. *BUT* it should never be released because it is an experiment, training exercise, or coding spike. And further, the skills involved in running an internal project via running an open source project are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest you to take a look into [Kohana framework](http://kohanaframework.org). Its an HMVC framework, with cascading directory structure. If you are looking for books on advanced topics, "[PHP Objects,
Patterns, and Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590593804)" by Matt Zandstra describes very well about Design patterns in PHP. "[Pro PHP Patterns, Frameworks, Testing and More](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598199)" is also an excellent book which discuss about many advanced topics.

Comment: "Pro PHP Patterns" is a horrible book: promoting use of global state and spreading misinformation about MVC pattern ..  and then there is os the ode to Zend Framework. But the "PHP Objects, Patterns, and Practice" book looks quite ok , at the first glance.

Comment: I dont think the book promotes the Global state, though not discouraging it.Infact the book does not stick in to the topic. Anyway it gives an intro to topics like spl, reflection, web services etc.

Answer (score 1):

[That tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php/) discusses implementing one's own MVC framework.  You can use an existing framework to implement applications using the MVC paradigm.  I happen to prefer Zend for this.  Here is a tutorial on using Zend MVC Framework:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

Comment: i intend to use MVC frameworks at later stage because as of for now i want to stick with understanding the structures and codes

Comment: There are two ways to study MVC:  in theory and in application.  MVC theory is a broad topic and many books exist from which you could read about it.  If you're interested in applying MVC in PHP, the best way to do it is to see how some existing open source projects implement MVC.

Comment: yeah well said, it is better i should searching for an ebook in amazon.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to start with Yii it easy to lear and use:
http://www.yiiframework.com/tour/

Answer (score 0):

To get my mind around the concept, I found a lot of reading to be helpful as well as seeing it implemented from scratch. Several resources:

Book Resource: PHP In Action, pages on MVC. (Great because mentions the difference between application and web MVC).

Understanding the Concept: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/modelinmvc/

Build Your Own Tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php/

Build Your Own Tutorial, more complex: http://www.nathandavison.com/posts/view/11/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-1-introduction