# Scalable app design in php

Tags: php, software-design

I'm a beginner php developer who is trying to build a social network for my school students. Knowing that the school has over 1000 students who are already active, I must have a plan of expanding / scale the code that I write.

Earlier it was just the LAMP Stack, now the modern web development is way more than that as I see, I'm truly kind of lost in what technologies to use and how to incorporate them to build a scalable app. I'm hoping to divide this application into 3 layers.

- Application layer (phalcon,reddis,apache,php)[mvc api centric]
- Database layer(mysql)
- UI layer - (html/css/js/)

This is where i need help, is this design approach good for a scalable app ? where can i improve ? any explanations, links for further reading will be a highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to find a flexible MVC framework such as [symfony](http://symfony.com/) and go from there.  Also, I would suggest, as a beginner you maybe go for a less complex project to find your feet.  Something like [this](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/) is a good way to start.

Comment: @DevDonkey Thank you, I'm abit familiar with OOP, and i perfectly understand MVC though i didn't find the need to use it in my little projects. 

Is it okay if i'm to use phalcon if i do have a understanding of OOP ? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. I cannot think of a particular reference guide to direct you to (although the [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/index.php) is a good place if you end up stuck with how to do something specific). I would suggest reading a bit of several results when you search "Getting started with MVC in PHP" and noting what they agree on.  That said, take a look at what I say below (and then ignore it as much as you please ;) ).

Firstly, you are wiser than many in sorting out a scalable design before launching into the project...

I'm excited to see [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/en/) in your list there already. However, as DevDonkey suggested, start with something simpler first (Phalcon is very powerful but to really get to grips with it you need a good grasp of PHP, particularly object-orientated programming).

**If you are completely new to PHP...**

... try building a small app (products table, view/add/edit/delete functionality) and learn the beginnings of the language that way, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929000/getting-started-with-php-mvc?answertab=active#tab-top) suggests. Things will go wrong and you'll discover lots of headaches when you want to change one feature and it affects everything else but that will help you to understand the importance of...

**MVC design**

From your question I can see you have at least heard of this. This is really where the layers of your application lie:

- *Model* - interactions with the database (retrieving/editing data) are handled through this. So you could have a MYSQL database and then your models provide a nice interface to interact with the data (generally you have one model for each table).
- *View* - this is the last layer, what the user sees. So you will make use of your html/css/js knowledge here. On this topic, unless you really want to do your own css consider using a **CSS Framework** such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It will really help speed up making your site look good and there are loads of free templates out there to use with it.
- *Controller* - this is the application logic. The controllers request/manipulate data through the models and then decide what to send to the views for rendering.

**Use a framework?**

Using a good framework can make your application more reliable and quicker to build. But using a framework without understanding it will be frustrating, slow and possibly result in worse code than if you didn't use one to begin with (as you employ hacks to get around the pieces of the framework you don't understand). My current favourite is [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/en/) but as a relative beginner to PHP I would suggest something more like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) although both [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) are also popular.

**Summary**

- Start small, learn, test ideas out and then build up to a bigger project.
- Get comfortable using PHP (including OOP style) before using a framework.
- Use an MVC framework

The layers you laid out in your question are good, but I would split it slightly differently (considering that MVC is the 3 layers)

- Application Layer - controllers, written in PHP, handles logic/manipulation, often the biggest layer
- Database Layer - models, written in PHP, you will also need a database which could be in your favourite database language - MySQL ;)
- UI Layer - views, possibly written in PHP (depending on the framework) but also HTML, CSS and JS as well as well as a templating language if you wish (e.g. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Volt](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html)), essentially a way to make the response from the controller nice for a human

**First Project (for CakePHP)**

[This blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) is a good place to start if you decide to use CakePHP.

**Getting started with Phalcon**

Phalcon is more powerful/verstile, but to get started with it I feel you have to be a better PHP developer than you do to get started with something like CakePHP. Take your time to understand each new concept with Phalcon, particularly [Dependency Injection](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-invo.html#dependency-injection).

Even having used CakePHP for the past 2 years and being familiar with MVC patterns and PHP, I still worked my way through all 7 of the [tutorials](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html) in Phalcon.

Having said this, my favourite thing about Phalcon is that it is *highly decoupled* - so it is fairly easy (after a while) to replace bits of it with your own extensions if it doesn't quite do what you want.

*Note about Phalcon:* It is not as popular as many other frameworks (although popularity is growing) and so you may have to spend some time digging around when you get stuck. However, the docs are improving all the time and the [forum](https://forum.phalconphp.com/) is very active. Unfortunately the number  answering questions about it on StackOverflow is still small compared to many other frameworks.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the clean explanations, This is pure gold for me, i cannot thank you enough.

Kvothe, i'm a bit familiar with OOP, here is something that i coded with oop, [link]https://github.com/dsginvilla/G2Valid[/link] please be kind to take a peek into this, i really want to try phalcon, but i understand, i might end up writing spaghetti code all over the place, If i can have your opinion on this, that would be great.

Thanks again.

Comment: That looks good, I also really like the fact that you include a thorough demo to go with it!
If you are comfortable with OOP then you can try Phalcon (see my answer edit), but I would suggest starting simple to get used to MVC design. One of the most important things to grasp is the **flow** through an MVC app. This usually means the dispatch loop ([Phalcon link](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html)).

Comment: Wow, that's some valuable information. I do have an understanding how MVC works, but i never wanted to try it, always felt to kept things simple since my projects were simple. But i do use dependency injection in my OOP already to keep things clean. Thank you Kvothe, i'll make sure i share the link as soon as its online. Thanks in advance.